# Select child nodes using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

What is the xslt select statement to transofrm xml from

```
<A>
  <B id="x">
    <C>
      <D>
      <D>
      <D>
      <D>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

to

```
<C name = "x">
  <D>
  <D>
  <D>
  <D>
</C>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is a short and simple, complete solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="B[@id]/C">
  <C name="{../@id}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
  </C>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be made well-formed):

```
<A>
    <B id="x">
        <C>
            <D/>
            <D/>
            <D/>
            <D/>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<C name="x">
   <D/>
   <D/>
   <D/>
   <D/>
</C>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use of template pattern matching.
2. Use of **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)**.

Comment: Nice compact solution :-)   minor issue: attribute `name` in result instead of `id`.

Answer (score 0):

With `.` being `C`:

```
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="../@id"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:copy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <out>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </out>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="C">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="../@id"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="A|B">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which transforms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
    <B id="x">
        <C>
            <D/>
            <D/>
            <D/>
            <D/>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<out>
    <C name="x">
        <D/>
        <D/>
        <D/>
        <D/>
    </C>
</out>
```